# Encountering issues while developing android hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk

[image]

[image]

Hello thanks for looking into this query.My problem is i am stuck here.I followed all instruction to create a hybrid project using the android SDK from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UZ1e.png) .My problem is i am not able to refer to the correct path and hence i am getting error stating "gen folder not found ".I went into properties but to show as path i am getting empty when i try adding path.Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UZ1e.png): [image]http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK

Comment: Did you run `install.sh` after getting the Mobile SDK for Android? Are you able to build a sample Android app without the Mobile SDK?

Comment: Thanks for your real quick reply.I am on windows and i ran cscript install.vbs for windows as mentioned in blog.I will try building sample android app without mobile SDK to figure out if the installation was an issue.

Comment: The first error i get is "Unable to resolve target 'android-8'" with import of project.

Comment: You also may want to refer to this article:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_Android

Comment: @joshbirk Thanks will try with native first .Hopefully some silly mistake i am doing .

Comment: If you can get the hello world native app running, then it should be straight forward to flip over to hybrid.  I had found the above link useful just for getting Eclipse to behave.

Comment: @joshbirk Just tried with hello world native app and same issue .

Comment: @metadady -Just finished creating a hello world app without sdk and works fine on emulator.wondering is there any directory structure i am missing on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mohit - open your Android SDK Manager and make sure that you have at least Android 2.2 (API v8) installed.

Comment: I have 4.2 and 4.1 .Is that not enough?I have updated my question with what is installed in my system.thanks

Comment: Mohit - I can see in your screenshot that Android 2.2 (API 8) is not checked. You will need to install it - the Mobile SDK template specifies that version.

Comment: Thanks i had to install 2.2 and 3.0 also too resolve the issue.Also looks like we need to import salesforceSDK from native folder location and have as a project and then import the sample hybrid app.All and all great article to get started thanks!