# Facing issue in running Hybrid android app - contact explorer salesforce demo app

Tags: mobilesdk, hybrid, salesforcesdk

i have followed the below steps and imported the contact explorer demo app provided in the salesforceSDK.

- Imported the SalesforceSDK in eclipse
- Imported the contact explorer app and add the salesforcesdk as library as mentioned in [Encountering issues while developing android hybrid mobile app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9460/encountering-issues-while-developing-android-hybrid-mobile-app).

Although the project got imported successfully with no errors, but when i run the app using the emulator it crashed immediately on opening. I am not clear on why it crashed since i have set both the remoteAccessConsumerKey and oauthRedirectURI correctly.

I see the below screen once Oauth authentication is done.

[image]

My AVD details are as below
[image]

Any help or pointers in where the possible issue would be really great.

Comment: Can you increase the memory to atleast 512MB.I see in your AVD the memory is 64M .Also try changing target device and sometimes that might help.

Comment: its very random mohit, yesterday it was working in the same AVD and today it starts crashing. I reinstalled eclipse ADT and its working now. I still don't find the rootcause and definitely don't want to keep Uninstall/Installing my bulky eclipse.